# Fade off text at edge of container into TRANSPARENT

Tags: css, text, overflow, transparent, fade

I'm afraid I already know the answer to this, but just to be sure:

Is there any way to fade out overflowing text at the edge of its container without having a solid color behind that container ?

So far I've found solutions that would involve using a linear gradient which would go from transparent to a certain color. A prerequisite for that solution to work is having a solid-colored background behind the container so that the outer end of the gradient can blend in with the background:

However, here's what I'd like to do:
[image]

As you can see, I don't have a solid-colored background, so that's not an option here.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an aproach will be using [This](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/), but this only works for `-webkit-`:

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800/city');
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'verdana';
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  width: 30%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container div span {
  display: block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, transparent);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>Suspendisse potenti. Fusce nec volutpat nibh. Aenean molestie pharetra augue eget tristique. Aenean pellentesque est sed nunc tincidunt vulputate. Nullam sed consectetur erat. Morbi quis condimentum nisl, eget tempor nulla. Donec nec aliquam erat. </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, very nice solution! Problem is, as with the answer below, if the browser window is resized or the view is zoomed in, nobody can predict where the text might break. It might be possible to mitigate that by playing around with the color stops of the gradient, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap the bottom text into `span` and change the `color` to `rgb` with `opacity`

```css
body {
  background: url(http://placeimg.com/640/480/any);
}
p {
  width: 220px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
p span:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
p span:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
p span:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
p span:nth-of-type(4) {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
```

```html
<p>penatibus et magnis dis parturient
  <br>montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  <br>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,
  <br>pellentesque eu, penatibus et
  <br>magnis dis parturient montes,
  <br>nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec
  <br>quam felis, ultricies nec nec,
  <br><span>pelpenat penatlen eu, penatibusf,</span>
  <br> <span>pelpenat penatlen eu, penatibusf,</span>
  <br> <span>pelpenat penatlen eu, penatibusf,</span>
  <span>pelpenat penatlen eu, penatibusf,</span>

  <br>
</p>
```

Comment: That approach makes sense, but since one can't predict where and how the text might break if e.g. the browser window is resized or zoomed in, this can't be used with overflowing text.